# How do I remove this Object from a Word 2010 Avery Label

Tags: microsoft-word

I am setting up a label template for use with Avery labels.

Avery have supplied a Word template.
In normal use they are great.
In my case my users are seniors over 80.
It is important that there is consistency in using the template otherwise my users get confused and upset.

The Avery templates do not show all the same items once you start a second page of labels.  There is an Insertion "character" in the cells on the first page that is not there on subsequent pages.
I want to remove this to avoid confusion.
However, I can't work out what it is.

- I can't select it in the normal way.
- I can't select it with Select Objects
- If I Select All and then Shift+F9 it does not    appear to be a
  field.

What is it?

How do I select and remove it?

[image]

Comment: These might be non-printing alignment guides, have you tried printing onto a plain sheet of paper?

Comment: That symbol is just a visual cue that is part of the editor.  It shows where you will be inputting.  It doesn't print.

Comment: Yes, these marks do not print.
However, I want to remove it from the document so as not to confuse elderly users.

Comment: @fixer1234.  It seems unlikely those are real insertion cursors of the sort you get in, for example, a text box.  Generally they are only visible when the editor is the active object so I would not expect to get more than one on a page. I get 21 on the first page.  Also they are only on the first page and not subsequent ones.  They should also disappear once text in entered into the editor.  These do not.

Comment: Are you referring to the ¤ or the gray I-shaped thing?

Comment: Oh right :-)  The I shaped thing.  The ¤ is standard for a cell.

Answer (score 1):

That symbol is the **End of Cell** mark.  It is displayed in cells and it marks the end of the last paragraph in the cell or the end of the cell. It reflects the formatting of the cell.

[image: EoC Mark]

You should be able to switch display of the symbol on or off with Show/Hide formatting marks.  I don't have ready access to Word, but if I remember correctly, this is not one of the symbols that has an individual override option (displayable even if formatting marks are off).

There are several ways to control display of formatting marks.  One is accessible through the paragraph marker symbol on the Home tab:

[image: Para marker]

The keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>*</kbd> should also work.

Good discussion of the formatting symbols and controlling them can be found [here](https://kranjac.wordpress.com/2011/08/14/formatting-marks-in-word-2010-showhide/) (these images are from that link).

**Update**

You added clarification in a comment on the question that you are interested in the "I-beam" cursor.  This has a single, universal purpose.  It marks the text insertion point and can be used for text selection.  It is actually controlled by the operating system rather than Word.

So that's what it is, and you raise the questions of why it appears in multiple locations, why the first sheet is different from subsequent sheets, and how to hide it (or make it less confusing for the users).

I don't have ready access to Word, so I can't validate all this information.  But, some thoughts and ideas:

- Without having the Avery template, it isn't clear how the individual labels are created (a table? text boxes? multiple small "pages"?).  Normally, there is only one insertion point, but for some reason, Word is showing the insertion point on each label on the first sheet.  "Why" is a mystery.
- I don't believe there is any way to hide them.  They aren't formatting symbols.  Anything you would do to modify it would likely need to be done at the OS level, and would affect all text activity in all applications.
- It's possible that the display of multiple insertion points is a bug.  You could try reloading the template or Word (and I believe Microsoft has an Office cleanup tool that checks for corruption).  It would be easier to investigate if the behavior can be replicated.
- It's possible that it is caused by a mismatch, such as the template being designed to work with an older or newer version of Word.  Or it could be an artifact of how that template was designed.  There are lots of label templates.  Try a different template.  There should be a way to build a template that doesn't display multiple insertion points.
- The active I-beam cursor blinks, so that may provide a mechanism to at least reduce confusion.  You can usually set the blink rate in the OS.  Set it to a more obvious speed.  It should blink only in the label that is in active focus.  So that may help to at least differentiate the multiple cursors.
- If all else fails, just educate your users.  Yes, it's one more confusing thing to learn, but it will be less confusing if you explain it up front.

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive evaluation.
It must be either a bug or a setting as I get it on the development machine but my users don't.  That is enough for me as it works for them.
I have put the document at https://www.dropbox.com/s/6sjvbk3jvi0kmjw/Address%20Labels.docx?dl=0?dl
If you're interested to take a look.